How to scroll down the child widgets of a Scaffold in Flutter?
What I am trying to achieve:
Create a floating button on the screen. When user clicks on it, make a screenshot, then try to scroll down on the page and any scrollable widget in the view port, one by one. Another screenshot would be made right after each scrolling action.
The current issue I have:
After tapping on the button, the initial screenshot works. But the scrolling function is not working.
Now I have the code like this:
Future<dynamic> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setBool('darkTheme', false);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key, this.home});

  final String? home;
  final screenshotController = ScreenshotController();

  Future<void> pressHandler(Widget? child) async {
    print('Button pressed, updated 3');

    if (child == null) {
      print('Child is null. Abort.');
      
      return;
    }

    try {
      // Initial screenshot
      await screenshotController
      .capture(delay: const Duration(milliseconds: 100))
      .then((image) {
        if (image != null) {
          print('Capture Done');
        } else {
          print('Capture Failed');
        }
      }).catchError((onError) {
        print('Capture Error: $onError');
      });

      // Try to scroll down
      await scrollEachItem(child, screenshotController);
    }
    catch(err) {
      print('Error: $err');
    }
  }

  bool isScrollable(dynamic widget) {
    return 
      // Check if widget is scrollable
      (
        widget is ListView &&
        // Check if widget has a scroll controller
        widget.controller != null &&
        // Check if widget has a max scroll extent
        widget.controller!.position.maxScrollExtent as num > 0 &&
        // Check if widget is not at the bottom
        widget.controller!.offset as num < widget.controller!.position.maxScrollExtent
      ) ||
      (
        widget is ScrollView &&
        // Check if widget has a scroll controller
        widget.controller != null &&
        // Check if widget has a max scroll extent
        widget.controller!.position.maxScrollExtent as num > 0 &&
        // Check if widget is not at the bottom
        widget.controller!.offset as num < widget.controller!.position.maxScrollExtent
      ) ||
      (
        widget is SingleChildScrollView &&
        // Check if widget has a scroll controller
        widget.controller != null &&
        // Check if widget has a max scroll extent
        widget.controller!.position.maxScrollExtent as num > 0 &&
        // Check if widget is not at the bottom
        widget.controller!.offset as num < widget.controller!.position.maxScrollExtent
      ) ||
      (
        widget is CustomScrollView &&
        // Check if widget has a scroll controller
        widget.controller != null &&
        // Check if widget has a max scroll extent
        widget.controller!.position.maxScrollExtent as num > 0 &&
        // Check if widget is not at the bottom
        widget.controller!.offset as num < widget.controller!.position.maxScrollExtent
      ) ||
      (
        widget is NestedScrollView &&
        // Check if widget has a scroll controller
        widget.controller != null &&
        // Check if widget has a max scroll extent
        widget.controller!.position.maxScrollExtent as num > 0 &&
        // Check if widget is not at the bottom
        widget.controller!.offset as num < widget.controller!.position.maxScrollExtent
      );
  }

  Future<int> scrollEachItem(
    dynamic child,
    ScreenshotController screenshotController,
  ) async {

    print('scrollEachItem is triggered');
    
    // Check if any scrollable widget exists
    // If not, return 0

    if (
      isScrollable(child) == true &&
      child.key != null &&
      child.key.currentContext != null &&
      child.key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() != null &&
      child.key.currentContext!.findRenderObject().size != null
    ) {
      print('Scrollable widget found');

      while (isScrollable(child) == true) {
        // Calculate the widget's height
        final num widgetHeight = (child.key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).size.height;

        final num remainingScrollingHeight = (child.controller!.position.maxScrollExtent as num) - (child.position.pixels as num);

        final num maxScrollableExtend = min(
          remainingScrollingHeight,
          widgetHeight
        );

        // Scroll down
        child.controller?.animateTo(
          maxScrollableExtend,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
        );
      }
    }

    final scrollableWidgets = <dynamic>[];

    if (child is Column) {
      for (final widget in child.children) {
        if (isScrollable(widget) == true) {
          scrollableWidgets.add(widget);
        }
      }
    }
    
    return 0;
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
            title: 'Food Market',
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            defaultTransition: Transition.rightToLeftWithFade,
            initialRoute: home ?? Routes.splash,
            getPages: allPages,
            builder: (context, child) {
              return Scaffold(
                body: Screenshot(
                  controller: screenshotController,
                  child: child,
                ),
                floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: ()=>Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 10), () => pressHandler(child)),
                  child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
                floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.miniEndFloat,
              );
            },
          );
  }
}

I was trying to solve the issues with AIs, and they said the scrollable widgets should have a key. But I can confirm that all widgets have their keys here.
I am quite new to Flutter and may have something going wrong here. Thanks in advance for any suggestions for the solution!

Inside body use ListView widget or If you use Column widget then Wrap Column widget to SingleChildSrcollView widget

I mean, the list widgets are inside other widgets, and I am trying to make the changes from the scaffold widgets containing the "other widgets".
